# How to enable triggers from other users aside from page owner

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks

I created a `facebook Page`, & a `Facebook App` that is subscribed to `webhooks`.

[image]

So I my external server was successfully able to receive messages sent from `my account`->`my page`(webhook triggers), but when other `other accounts` send message to `my page`, no webhook gets triggered.

Any leads why? Do I need my application to be submitted & reviewed by facebook team for this feature to enable?

Will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you bot is approved and set to public, only users with the Developer, Tester, or Admin role can interact with it.

Comment: Can you add source of reference for your answer btw @amuramoto?